# installation of kali linux in windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, operating-systems

[image]

I have twice "disk". One is my windows I have another unallocated disk. Should I make it a volume to install `Kali Linux`?

Comment: [Please read this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/53467).

Comment: @gronostaj Sorry! I am not new to `Kali Linux`. I had used `Kali Linux` earlier but, I need Windows nowadays also. That's why I had to uninstalled the `Kali Linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *one disk* with one allocated partition surrounded by unallocated space.

Evidently, you have deleted the recovery partition of Windows of 501 MB
at the beginning of the disk, for some unknown (and wrong) reason.

To answer: Yes, you may install Kali Linux. Just give it the unallocated space
at the end of the disk (167.58 GB).

Comment: So, I don't have to make that **volume**, do I?

Comment: You can do that during the installation, which is best. You don't have to do anything before the installation.